# WPF/MVVM: Delegating a domain Model collection to a ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dns, delegates, collections

A domain model collection (normally a List or IEnumerable) is **delegated** to a ViewModel.

Thats means my CustomerViewModel has a order collection of type List or IEnumerable.

No change in the list is recognized by the bound control. But with ObservableCollection it is.

This is a problem in the MVVM design pattern.

How do you cope with it?

**UPDATE**: Sample of how I do it:

```
 public class SchoolclassViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Schoolclass _schoolclass;
    private ObservableCollection<PupilViewModel> _pupils = new ObservableCollection<PupilViewModel>();        

    public SchoolclassViewModel(Schoolclass schoolclass)
    {
        _schoolclass = schoolclass;
        _schoolclass.Pupils = new List<Pupil>();

        foreach (var p in schoolclass.Pupils)           
            Pupils.Add(new PupilViewModel(p));            
    }

    public Schoolclass GetSchoolclass 
    {
        get { return _schoolclass; } 
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }       

    public string SchoolclassName
    {
        get { return _schoolclass.SchoolclassName;}
        set
        { 
            if(_schoolclass.SchoolclassName != value)
            {                    
                _schoolclass.SchoolclassName = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("SchoolclassName");
            }

        }
    }   

    public ObservableCollection<PupilViewModel> Pupils
    {
        get{ return _pupils;}
        set
        {
            _pupils = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Pupils");
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this a problem with the MVVM design pattern? Changes in the list are recognized only when the collection is observable. This is of all programming, not just MVVM.

Comment: it is not a general problem, because only with the MVVM design pattern you delegate a model to a viewmodel.

The domain models/collection must be developed independently from the ViewModel requirements which are having a ObservableCollection for change notification in data binding.

Its about separation of concern between the ViewModel(Notify when collection changes what is a UI requirement) and the Model (no change notification at all because the model is not bound to the View!)

Comment: You could expose your ObservableCollection<T> as an IEnumerable<T>, and as long as the underlying type is an ObservableCollection<T> binding still works as expected, right? (I think this is right, but I don't really recall now).

Comment: I agree it's not a problem with MVVM.  However it is a hassle you simply have to deal with if you want to get the full benefits of databinding.  A similar hassle is having to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your domain objects if you want to bind directly to their properties.

Comment: You always have the option of using Dynamic Proxies and automatically conforming your Models to a more MVVM friendly format. You should be able to Weave in PropertyChanged and maybe even ObservableCollections.

Comment: @Phil

You agree to what? Nobody here has yet made clear why its not a MVVM problem.

domain layer containing model: returns IEnumerable<T>/List<T>
ui layer containing viewmodel wants: bind to ObservableCollection<T> 

Where do you not see a problem directly related to MVVM Phil ?

Comment: I disagree that this is a problem in the design pattern.  Your domain model doesn't support change notification, and you want to build a UI that responds to changes in the data.  The design pattern's a way of accomplishing this goal.  It's the *goal* that's the problem.  If you want to write a UI that isn't robust, nothing's stopping you.

Comment: @msfanboy: While MVVM is pretty specific to WPF and Silverlight (I haven't seen it used elsewhere), it is a design pattern that describes how concerns are separated when using WPF/SL .  The issue you are describing has to do with the way databinding works--in other words, the WPF/SL framework implementation.

Comment: @Phil: I prefered your answer mostly and your sentence above (although its not in the solution just in the comment :P ) it makes things more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'll go ahead and add my thoughts as an answer instead of in the comments. :)

I think the bottom line is that this is just the reality of the way WPF and databinding work.  In order for two-way databinding to operate, collections need a means of notifying controls that are bound to them, and the standard lists and collections used in most domain objects don't/won't/shouldn't support this.  As I mentioned in a comment, being required to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for non-collection properties is another requirement that may not be met by a standard domain object.

Domain objects are not intended to to be viewmodels, and for this reason you may find that you need to map back and forth between the two types of objects.  This is not dissimilar to having to map back and forth between domain objects and data access objects.  Each type of object has a different function in the system, and each should be specifically designed to support their own role in the system.

All that said,  Agies's idea of using AOP to automatically generate proxy classes is very interesting, and something I intend to look into.

Comment: aren`t these proxy classes just a clone of the domain models? like ViewModel is most times a clone of a domain model!?

Comment: You might say a "representation" or a "projection" but not a "clone", and for exactly the reasons above.  The viewmodel addresses a different concern than the domain object does, just like a domain object addresses a different concern than a DAO.  In some cases, if the needs across layers are really that similar, it might be possible to use the same objects.  For example, you might have your domain objects implement INotifyPropertyChanged.  Completely supporting two way databinding in your lists might be more challenging (again, you might look at AOP).

Comment: well atm I have 3 aggregated domain models. They are all supporting 2way databinding, PropertyChanges and CollectionChanges.

Now need for ViewModels as they would be a pure copy of the models, that would make no sense at all!

Answer (score 3):

I deal with this by not doing it the way you describe.

If I need to present a `Foo` object and its related `Bar` objects in the view, the `FooViewModel` will generally implement a `Bars` property of type `ObservableCollection<BarViewModel>`.

Note that this is irrespective of whether or not the underlying `Foo` class  has a `Bars` property of type `IEnumerable<Bar>`.  The `Foo` class might not.  The application might not even need to be able to iterate over all of the `Bar` objects for a `Foo`, except in the UI.

**Edit**

When my view is a simple representation of the application's object model, I pretty much do things as you do in your sample.  The code in my constructor is generally a bit more compact:

```
_Bars = new ObservableCollection<BarViewModel>(
   _Foo.Bars.Select(x => new BarViewModel(x)));
```

but it's essentially the same thing.

But this assumes that `Foo` actually exposes a `Bars` property.  It might not.  Or maybe only some `Bar` objects should appear in the view.  Or maybe they should appear intermingled with other objects, and the `FooViewModel` should expose a `CompositeCollection` of some kind.

The point I'm making is that the view model is a model of the *view*.  This doesn't necessarily have a direct correspondence to the underlying object model.

To pick a simple example:  My program may give the user a way of putting items into five different categories by dragging and dropping them into five different `ListBox` controls.  Ultimately, doing this sets a `Category` property on the `Item` object.  My view model is going to have a collection of `CategoryViewModel` objects, each with a property of type `ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>`, so that dragging items back and forth between collections is simple to implement.

The thing is, there may not even *be* a `Category` class in the application's object model, let alone a collection of `Category` objects.  `Item.Category` might just be a property of type `string`.  The `CategoryViewModel` isn't mirroring the application's object model.  It only exists to support the view in the UI.

Comment: @Robert

Your comment sounds interesting and confusing to me the same time.

I have updated the initial question with a code sample how I do it. Can 

you describe your way with my sample somehow? I do not understand 

everything what you described /:

Comment: @Robert: I think you are confirming his complaint, which is that every time you want to use a collection from your domain model in your viewmodel, you have to project it onto an ObservableCollection (and project it back if you want to do something like save it).

Comment: Sure.  But the complaint is really, "I want to provide a non-trivial user interface, and my domain model doesn't implement property-change notification and value conversion and commands."  If you want to implement that stuff in your domain model, you can, and then refactor it out into a view model once you realize that coupling the view to the domain model causes a lot of problems that you'd rather not have.  Creating view models is just doing that refactoring in advance.

Comment: Given that ObservableCollection has been moved out of the WPF namesapce in .Net 4, I suppose there is no reason your model couldn't implement its collections as an OC. Sure you want your Models to be fairly lightweight, of course if thats the case you should be using arrays, I doubt OC is that much heavier then a List.

Comment: @Agies

The reason why I can NOT use ObservableCollection in the model is because I get data from a datacontext which returns aggregated models of type IEnumerable => http://loungerepo.codeplex.com/

Comment: "...@Robert: I think you are confirming his complaint, which is that every time you want to use a collection from your domain model in your viewmodel, you have to project it onto an ObservableCollection (and project it back if you want to do something like save it)...."

@PHIL

great you have really recognized the problem I am having. I hope the other also understand it now!

Comment: So these Model object are actually your entity objects? That changes the issue greatly, I thought these were DTOs that you were spawning from your Entity objects.

Comment: @Agies

yes my entity objects there are!

How does this change the issue greatly?

Regarding the new wisdom you gained what would you advise me Agies? :)

Answer (score 0):

What I do is instead of using ObservableCollection in my domain model is use my own collection type that implements the [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) interface amongst other useful standard and custom interfaces. My way of thinking is that much like [Rockford Lhotka](http://www.lhotka.net/) suggests in his book that change notification is useful in to more than just a presentation layer since other business objects within the domain layer often need some sort of notification when state changes in another object.

With this methodology you could create your own collection type that still has the benefits of change notification and as well as what ever custom behaviors you need. The base class for your collection could be implemented as purely infrastructure code and then a subclass could be created that could contain business logic using the subtype layering techinque used in [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470147563). So in the end you could have a collection that can wrap types of IEnumerable<> and provide the change notification stuff your looking for as well for both your domain model and presentation code.